# Footer isn't at the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css, footer

My footer isn't at the bottom of the page.

Solutions I have tried:
- W3C validator (now passed)
- Cleaning up code (indenting etc)
- Checked all divs and tags were ended

None of the above worked, and the problem still persists.

Here is a screen shot of the problem:
[image]

Please not the red bar across the middle is the footer. Its meant to be at the bottom, not in the middle of the page.

My Html:

```
<body>

<div id="call-back"></div>

<div id="header">

<br>

    <span style="color:#BB2131;">
        Welcome to Madhouse Creative    </span>

    <div style="float:right;">
        <img src="images/social/twitter.png" class="social_button" alt="">
        <img src="images/social/facebook.png" class="social_button" alt="">
    </div>

<br>
<br>

    <img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo">

    <div id="nav">
        <ul id="list-nav">
            <li><a href="index.php">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="about-us.php">ABOUT</a></li>
            <li><a href="portfolio.php">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact-us.php">CONTACT</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</div>

<div id="head-slider-break"></div>  

<div id="home-slider">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).load(function() 
            {
                $('#slider').nivoSlider();
            });
    </script>

    <div class="slider-wrapper theme-default">

        <div class="ribbon"></div>

        <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider" style="margin-top:30px;">
            <img src="images/middleimage3.png" alt="" >
            <img src="images/middleimage.png" alt="" >
            <img src="images/middleimage2.png" alt="" >
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

<div id="wrapper">  

    <h1>A <span style="color:#BB2131;">WEB</span> AND <span style="color:#BB2131;">GRAPHIC DESIGN</span> COMPANY</h1>

    <p>Madhouse Creative is a new, innovative company looking to bring a fresh look to how businesses market and present themselves on the internet with elegant designs that contain endless potential. Specialists in user immersing visualisations, they bring a unique approach to brand identity.</p>
    <p>Based in Kent, working with business throughout the UK. We aim to change the way your business is seen, heard and talked about. Contact us today to see how we could help your business.</p>

    <div style="width:960px;border:1px dashed #cccccc; margin-top:40px;"></div>

    <h1>WHAT <span style="color:#BB2131;">WE</span> CAN <span style="color:#BB2131;">OFFER</span>?</h1>


    <div id="what-we-offer" style="border:2px solid #cccccc;">

        <div class="col">
            <div class="red-box">
                <h3 style="margin-top:0px;">WEB DESIGN</h3>
            </div>
            <img src="images/design-web-image.png" class="home-thumb-image" alt="">
        </div>

        <div class="col">
            <div class="red-box">
                <h3 style="margin-top:0px;">WEB MARKETING</h3>
            </div>
            <img src="images/web-marketing.png" class="home-thumb-image" alt="">
        </div>

        <div class="col">
            <div class="red-box">
                <h3 style="margin-top:0px;">GRAPHIC DESIGN</h3>
            </div>
            <img src="images/graphic-design.png" class="home-thumb-image" alt="">
        </div>

        <div class="col">
            <div class="red-box">
                <h3 style="margin-top:0px;">LOGO DESIGN</h3>
            </div>
            <img src="images/logodesign.png" class="home-thumb-image" alt="">
        </div>

        <div class="col">
            <div class="red-box">
                <h3 style="margin-top:0px;">VISUALIZATION</h3>
            </div>
            <img src="images/visualization.png" class="home-thumb-image" alt="">
        </div>

        <div class="col">
            <div class="red-box">
                <h3 style="margin-top:0px;">WEB APPS</h3>
            </div>
            <img src="images/web-marketing2.png" class="home-thumb-image" alt="">
        </div>

</div>



</div>
<div id="footer">

</div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
body {
background-color:#ffffff;
margin: 0px;
}
h1 {
font-family: "Helvetica Neue" bold;
color:#cccccc;
font-size: 35pt;
line-height: 1.1;
}
#content h1 {font-family: "Helvetica Neue" bold;
color:#cccccc;
font-size: 35pt;
line-height: 1.1;
margin-bottom: -10px;
}

h2, h3, h4, h5, h6{
font-family: "Helvetica Neue" bold;
color:#808080;
}
a {color:#BB2131; text-decoration: none;}
a:hover {color:#BB2131; text-decoration: underline;}
#header{height: 50px; width: 100%;font-family: "Helvetica Neue";
}
#home-slider {
margin:0 auto;width:960px; height:auto;
}
#head-slider-break {height:60px;}
#wrapper{
width:960px;
margin:0 auto;
color:#000000;
font-family: "Helvetica Neue";
font-size:12pt;
line-height:1.2;
word-spacing:1.5;
}
#social{
text-align: right;
padding-top: 4px;
}
#header1{height: 50px; width: 100%; background-image: url(images/header.png);}
#headtxt {margin-top: -40px;}
#nav {width:400px; float: right;}
ul#list-nav {
list-style:none;
padding:0px;
float: right;
}
ul#list-nav li {
display:inline;
}
ul#list-nav li a {
text-decoration:none;
height: 40px;
padding: 7px;
color:#808080;
float:left;
text-align:center;
line-height: 3;
font-size: 15px;
font-family: "Helvetica Neue" bold;
font-weight: bolder;
}

ul#list-nav li a:hover {
color:#BB2131;
}

#head{
color: #ffff66;
font-family: ;
font-size: 30px;
}
.container {
padding-left: 20px;
padding-right: 20px;
}

.social_button {
width:36px;
height:36px;
}
#index_middle_image {
margin-top:30px;
}
#request_call_back {
margin-left:10px;
}
.nivoSlider {
    position:relative;
    width:960px; /* Change this to your images width */
    height:397px; /* Change this to your images height */
    background:url(images/loading.gif) no-repeat 50% 50%;
}
.nivoSlider img {
    position:relative;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    display:none;
}
.nivoSlider a {
    border:0;
    display:block;
}
#redbox {background-image:url('images/red-box-for-web.png'); width:160px;
 height:75px;;color:#ffffff; font-size:14pt;
font-family: "Helvetica Neue"; float:left; text-align:center; line-height:80px; padding-right: 30px;overflow: hidden;}
#greybox {background-image:url('images/grey-box-for-web.png'); width:160px; 
height:75px;color:#BB2131; font-size:14pt;
font-family: "Helvetica Neue"; float:left;text-align:center;line-height:80px; padding-right: 30px; overflow: hidden;}


#what-we-offer .col {float: left; width: 315px; padding: 2px;}
#what-we-offer {width: 960px;margin-bottom: 10px;
padding: 5px;
height: auto;
float: left;}
.red-box {
background-image: url(images/red-box.png);
width: 315px;
height: 68px;
margin-bottom: 5px;
margin-top: 5px;
}

#what-we-offer h3 {color: #ffffff; text-align: center; line-height: 4;}

.home-thumb-image {width:315px; height: 179px;}

#call-back{background-image: url(images/REQUEST-CALL-BACK-2.png); float: right; width: 100px; height: 100px; top: 0; right: 0; position: fixed; }

#footer {background-image: url(images/footer2.png); height: 300px;} 

#home-text {width:960px; height:auto;}
#header {
width:960px;
margin:0 auto;
font-family: "Helvetica Neue";
font-size:12pt;
word-spacing:1.5;
}
```

I have done my best to include any necessary code and edit out any unnecessary CSS.

If anyone could help diagnose what is wrong with my code and/or what I need to add it would be a great help.

Comment: The footer div is empty. Am I wrong? What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are floating `#what-we-offer`.  Add `clear:both` to #footer to make sure you clear all the floating elements.

Comment: beat me too it.  Clearing the footer should fix the issue.  I deleted my answer and up-rated his.

Comment: great answer. thanks. didnt know you had to clear something if you floated something before it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `clear: both;` to your footer's CSS. This should solve the problem.