# Footer stuck in middle of page

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm having Sticky footer issues with this site:

http://dev.epicwebdesign.ca/allshipsrise/events/

For some reason or another, The #page div is limiting itself to the header.

I can't figure this out. All tags are closed, etc. The W3C Conformance checker only complains about "the acronym element is obsolete. Use the abbr element instead.". That is wordpress's doing.

It's similar to [Footer isn't at the bottom of the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9369688/footer-isnt-at-the-bottom-of-the-page) However I have set clear:both on the footer.

The footer is fine when the page is too tall. I need it on the bottom even when it's not.

There were a couple underlying issues, mostly from trying to compensate for the real issue. (Not setting body height:100%) They're all sorted out now.

Comment: How should the page look like?

Comment: The footer should be on the bottom, not in the middle. I found an extra div that was floated left and removed it, may be part of the issue

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your body set the height to 100% and your footer will be displayed until the end of your page :)

Comment: No... no it won't.  You obviously didn't look at the problem

Comment: I visited his website and did the exact thing and BAM! I had a footer until the end of the page.

Comment: Wow. That actually did it. I had "min-height: 100%;" set, which I would assume would work, but changing it to "height: 100%;" did.

Comment: @t.thielemans I did try it... still looks like garbage in my FF

Comment: @Mike Please don't downvote to any answer unless you are absolutely sure.... just add a comment saying this is not the right answer. downvoting is not the thing we are here for

Comment: @Dipaks I didn't downvote anything... but thanks for trying!  Please refrain from commenting on situations you obviously don't understand, or from jumping to conclusions on topics that don't apply to you.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few problems.  With `element.style` you are using absolute positioning and raising it up 85px.  Change that to `position="relative"` and remove the `bottom` attribute.

This:

```
element.style {
    bottom: 85px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Becomes:

```
element.style {
    bottom: 0px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Thats actually on a part of the footer I wanted to raise up a bit, not on the footer itself.

Comment: @EPICWebDesign From what I'm looking at, what I'm referring to appears to be out of place and my answer suggests a remedy.  If that suggestion doesn't do what you're after, then I've misinterpreted your question and/or you haven't explained your question thoroughly.

Comment: @EPICWebDesign I'm referring to the "Design by Chipper Studio | Development by EPIC Web Design" which is way up out of place, especially when the screen is smaller.  My suggested answer will fix that problem and bring it down to where I would expect it to be.

Comment: Oh, Now I see the confusion. I was talking about the actual <footer></footer> footer.

Comment: @Mike, I fully agree that part might need to be in the footer itself, but that's a different issue to the one he is referring in his post ;) So for that, +1!

Comment: @t.thielemans Without a screenshot or a more elaborate question, I can only speculate as to what he's referring to.  What I addressed was the only problem I was seeing with the page.  Hope it helps, OP!

Answer (score 0):

Or another work around would be changing the `margin-top:` to  100%

Answer (score 0):

Removing `position:relative` solves the problem. Just remove this element using firebug and you will get the result.

Comment: I'm using chrome's Developer tools, when I did that it pushed the footer off the screen.

Comment: change it from code and refresh your page. What is the result then?

Comment: Not worth messing with, it's working fine now with absolute positioning.